# Button Omission Options

Tags: html, node.js, vue.js, ejs

I'm working on a nodejs project and over the last couple days I put together a dynamic form using Vuejs. However, for the list I am confused as to how I should omit the delete button for the first item of the dynamic portion of the from.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Homemade</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="newRecipeContainer">
        <form action="/recipes/createRecipe" method="POST">
            <div class="recipeNameContainer">
                <label class="recipeNameLabel">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="recipeName">
            </div>

            <div class="directionsContainer">
                <button class="addDirectionButton" type="button" @click="addDirectionForm">Add Another Direction</button>
        
                <div class="allDirections" v-for="(direction, index) in directions">
                    <label class="direction">{{ index + 1 }}.)</label>
                    <input type="text" name="directions" v-model="direction.direction">
                    
                    <button class="deleteDirectionButton" type="button" @click="deleteDirectionForm(index)">Delete Direction</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="recipeImage">
                <input type="file" accept="image/*" /> 
            </div>

            <button class="createRecipeButton" type="submit">Create Recipe</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="/controls/newRecipeControl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '.directionsContainer',
    data: {
        directions: [
            {
                direction: ''
            }
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        addDirectionForm: function(){
            this.directions.push({
                direction: ''
            })
        },

        deleteDirectionForm: function(index){
            if(index != 0)
                this.directions.splice(index, 1)
        }
    }
})
```

Initially, my thought was to use an if statement in the html to check whether index is equal to 0, however, that errors out. I am using ejs to embed javascript into my html. I am unsure how to best approach this, any suggestions?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should be able to put `v-if="index > 0"` on your button element

Comment: That solved it thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Vue's [conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) on your button element to only show it for indexes above zero 1️⃣.

```html
<button
  v-if="index > 0" 1️⃣
  class="deleteDirectionButton" 
  type="button" 
  @click="deleteDirectionForm(index)"
>Delete Direction</button>
```